# Gradle build have some errors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle errors:

> Error:(63, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2
>
> Error:(66, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2
>
> Error:(65, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2
>
> Error:(62, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2
>
> Error:(64, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2
>
> Error:(55, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyPassword keyPassword
            storeFile filestoreFile
            storePassword storePassword
            keyAlias keyAlias
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId applicationId
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: manifestPlaceholders , onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar'
        exclude 'libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.8'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.hamsaadev:Persian-Date-Picker-Dialog:V1.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.5.8@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I try :

1. gradle setting offline work is unchecked
2. http proxy
3. remove http proxy

proxy but problem has remind.

android studio version : 2.3.3

gradle.build(Module:app) :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: connect to internet and sync gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update sdk to 26.0.2 solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to bottom of `app` level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then Sync your project. Maybe it will fix your problem

EDIT:
Considering Moonbloom's suggestion,

Update app level `build.gradle` with:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

instead of

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: tnx. but not changed.

Comment: has the error changed? if yes, please update new error.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Any place where it says either `mavenCentral()` or `jcenter()`, you should add the following:

```
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

You should also add both `mavenCentral()` and `jcenter()` if they're missing from any of the blocks.

These lines basically tell Gradle where to look for libraries that you're trying to include. The maven.google.com one is new, and is the only place the absolutely newest Google Play libraries are hosted.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in the botton of app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

change all the versions from 11.0.2 to 11.0.1

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
```

Comment: I try on 11.0.0 ,  11.0.1 and 11.0.2 but solved my problem by upgrading sdk.